# Stored procedure result in HTML format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I require the changes in the below script so that we have to receive the results of the stored procedure sp_validatelogins as mail in HTML format.

The below is the script .

```
USE [test]
GO

ALTER PROC [dbo].[DBA_REPORT] 
@emailrecipients NVARCHAR(256)  
AS  
BEGIN  

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @EmailSubject NVARCHAR(128)
       ,@ReportTitle NVARCHAR(128)
       ,@ReportTitle2 NVARCHAR(128)
       ,@ReportTitle3 NVARCHAR(128)
       ,@ReportTitle4 NVARCHAR(128)
       ,@ReportTitle5 NVARCHAR(128)
       ,@ReportTitle6 NVARCHAR(128)
       ,@ReportTitle7 NVARCHAR(128)
       ,@TableHTML NVARCHAR(max)
       ,@TableHTML2 NVARCHAR(max)
       ,@TableHTML3 NVARCHAR(max)
       ,@TableHTML4 NVARCHAR(max)
       ,@TableHTML5 NVARCHAR(max)
       ,@TableHTML6 NVARCHAR(max)
       ,@TableHTML7 NVARCHAR(max)
       ,@Mergedtable NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@sql nvarchar(max)

SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN
       SELECT  @EmailSubject = 'DBA REPORT'
              ,@ReportTitle =  'Report of jobs that failed in the past 24 hours'
              ,@ReportTitle2 = 'Report of disabled jobs'
              ,@ReportTitle3 = 'Invalid Logins'
              ,@ReportTitle4 = 'Logins having no permissions'
              ,@ReportTitle5 = 'Logins having sysadmin permissions'
              ,@ReportTitle6 = 'Report on Suspect Pages'
              ,@ReportTitle7 = 'Report on databases'

--3rd.create TEMP TABLE to hold results of SP call 
          create table #invalidlogins(
                                       A_SID varchar(128),
                                       A_LOGIN varchar(128))

           insert into #invalidlogins
           exec sp_validatelogins

--select from the table variable Only if the data exists

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #invalidlogins) 
 BEGIN    


---Creating  HTML table
              SET @TableHTML3 = '<html><head><style>'
               + 'td {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:11pt;} ' 
               +'</style></head><body>' + '<div style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:5px; margin-bottom:15px; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.3em; font-family:calibri;">'
               + @ReportTitle3 + '</div>' + '<div style="margin-left:50px; font-family:Calibri;"><table cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1 border=1>' + '<tr bgcolor=#4b6c9e>'
               + '<td align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>A_LOGIN</b></font></td></tr>'

              DECLARE @EmailBody3 NVARCHAR(max)

              SELECT @EmailBody3 = (
                           SELECT td =A_SID
                                  ,td =A_LOGIN
                           FROM #invalidlogins
                           FOR XML RAW('tr')
                                  ,ELEMENTS
                           )

              SET @EmailBody3 = REPLACE(@EmailBody3, '<td>', '<td align=center><font face="calibri">')
              SET @EmailBody3 = REPLACE(@EmailBody3, '</td>', '</font></td>')
              SET @EmailBody3 = REPLACE(@EmailBody3, '_x0020_', SPACE(1))
              SET @EmailBody3 = REPLACE(@EmailBody3, '_x003D_', '=')
              SET @EmailBody3 = REPLACE(@EmailBody3, '<TRRow>0</TRRow>', '')

              SET @TABLEHTML3 = @TABLEHTML3 + @EmailBody3 + '</table></div></body></html>'
              SET @TABLEHTML3 = '<div style="color:Black; font-size:11pt; font-family:Calibri; width:100px;">' + @TableHTML3 + '</div>'

              DROP TABLE #invalidlogins


 -- Send the mail in this block as well.
    END

         SET @Mergedtable = @TableHTML+@TableHTML2+@TableHTML3+@TableHTML5+@TableHTML7

       EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'SQLDBA Profile'
                     ,@recipients = @emailrecipients 
                     ,@Body = @Mergedtable
                     ,@subject = @EmailSubject
                     ,@Body_format = 'HTML'



  END















END









GO
```

Comment: Have a look at the answer [Execute Sql statement and send result to email](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/168424/145949)

Comment: Receiving an empty mail

Comment: Do you have invalid logins? IF you don't that might be why. Does `exec sp_validatelogins` return anything? What do you want to happen if nothing is returned? EmailBody & TABLEHTML  will be NULL if there are no results returned by it.

Comment: If there is no data i should not receive any mail but i'm receiving empty mail so what i need to change to not receive any mail if no data exist

Comment: @Teja Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

I found some years ago a query that can transform any query into HTML:

```
-- Description: Turns a query into a formatted HTML table. Useful for emails. 
-- Any ORDER BY clause needs to be passed in the separate ORDER BY parameter.
-- =============================================
CREATE PROC [dbo].[spQueryToHtmlTable] 
(
  @query nvarchar(MAX), --A query to turn into HTML format. It should not include an ORDER BY clause.
  @orderBy nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, --An optional ORDER BY clause. It should contain the words 'ORDER BY'.
  @html nvarchar(MAX) = NULL OUTPUT --The HTML output of the procedure.
)
AS
BEGIN   
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF @orderBy IS NULL BEGIN
    SET @orderBy = ''  
  END

  SET @orderBy = REPLACE(@orderBy, '''', '''''');

  DECLARE @realQuery nvarchar(MAX) = '
    DECLARE @headerRow nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @cols nvarchar(MAX);    

    SELECT * INTO #dynSql FROM (' + @query + ') sub;

    SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols + '', '''''''', '', '''') + ''['' + name + ''] AS ''''td''''''
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
    WHERE object_id = object_id(''tempdb..#dynSql'')
    ORDER BY column_id;

    SET @cols = ''SET @html = CAST(( SELECT '' + @cols + '' FROM #dynSql ' + @orderBy + ' FOR XML PATH(''''tr''''), ELEMENTS XSINIL) AS nvarchar(max))''    

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @cols, N''@html nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT'', @html=@html OUTPUT

    SELECT @headerRow = COALESCE(@headerRow + '''', '''') + ''<th>'' + name + ''</th>'' 
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
    WHERE object_id = object_id(''tempdb..#dynSql'')
    ORDER BY column_id;

    SET @headerRow = ''<tr>'' + @headerRow + ''</tr>'';

    SET @html = ''<table border="1">'' + @headerRow + @html + ''</table>'';    
    ';

  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @realQuery, N'@html nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT', @html=@html OUTPUT
END
GO
-----------------------------------------------------
USAGE:

DECLARE @html nvarchar(MAX);
EXEC spQueryToHtmlTable @html = @html OUTPUT,  @query = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.People', @orderBy = N'ORDER BY FirstName';

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'Foo',
    @recipients = 'bar@baz.com;',
    @subject = 'HTML email',
    @body = @html,
    @body_format = 'HTML',
    @query_no_truncate = 1,
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If `exec sp_validatelogins` does not return a resultset, the `#invalidlogins` will be empty.

As a result, setting `@EmailBody` to values in the `#invalidlogins` table will also set `@EmailBody` to NULL. The same is true for `@TableHTML`

```
     SET @TABLEHTML = @TABLEHTML + @EmailBody + '</table></div></body></html>'
```

This might be why you are receiving empty mails.

You could resolve this by inserting the `'No Invalid Logins'` value instead of selecting it:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #invalidlogins) 
BEGIN    
SELECT A_LOGIN as Invalid_Logins FROM #Invalidlogins 
END 
ELSE BEGIN
INSERT INTO #invalidlogins(A_LOGIN)
SELECT 'No Invalid Logins' as Invalid_logins 
END
```

Result for  `@EmailBody`

```
<tr><td align=center><font face="calibri">No Invalid Logins</font></td></tr>
```

Result for  `@TableHTML`

```
<div style="color:Black; font-size:11pt; font-family:Calibri; width:100px;"><html><head><style>td {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:11pt;} </style></head><body><div style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:5px; margin-bottom:15px; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.3em; font-family:calibri;">bla</div><div style="margin-left:50px; font-family:Calibri;"><table cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1 border=1><tr bgcolor=#4b6c9e><td align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>A_LOGIN</b></font></td></tr><tr><td align=center><font face="calibri">No Invalid Logins</font></td></tr></table></div></body></html></div>
```

Or you could not send an alert if the procedure does not return anything.

**Edit 2**

> If there is no data i should not receive any mail but i'm receiving
>   empty mail so what i need to change to not receive any mail if no data
>   exist

Then you should specify

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #invalidlogins)  BEGIN

--Run all following statements & send the mail


END
```

such as

```
USE [test]
GO

ALTER PROC [dbo].[DBA_REPORT] 
@emailrecipients NVARCHAR(256)  
AS  
BEGIN  

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @EmailSubject NVARCHAR(128)
       ,@ReportTitle NVARCHAR(128)
       ,@ReportTitle2 NVARCHAR(128)
       ,@ReportTitle3 NVARCHAR(128)
       ,@ReportTitle4 NVARCHAR(128)
       ,@ReportTitle5 NVARCHAR(128)
       ,@ReportTitle6 NVARCHAR(128)
       ,@ReportTitle7 NVARCHAR(128)
       ,@TableHTML NVARCHAR(max)
       ,@TableHTML2 NVARCHAR(max)
       ,@TableHTML3 NVARCHAR(max)
       ,@TableHTML4 NVARCHAR(max)
       ,@TableHTML5 NVARCHAR(max)
       ,@TableHTML6 NVARCHAR(max)
       ,@TableHTML7 NVARCHAR(max)
       ,@Mergedtable NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@sql nvarchar(max)

SET NOCOUNT ON


       SELECT  @EmailSubject = 'DBA REPORT'
              ,@ReportTitle =  'Report of jobs that failed in the past 24 hours'
              ,@ReportTitle2 = 'Report of disabled jobs'
              ,@ReportTitle3 = 'Invalid Logins'
              ,@ReportTitle4 = 'Logins having no permissions'
              ,@ReportTitle5 = 'Logins having sysadmin permissions'
              ,@ReportTitle6 = 'Report on Suspect Pages'
              ,@ReportTitle7 = 'Report on databases'

--3rd.create TEMP TABLE to hold results of SP call 
          create table #invalidlogins(
                                       A_SID varchar(128),
                                       A_LOGIN varchar(128))

           insert into #invalidlogins
           exec sp_validatelogins

--select from the table variable Only if the data exists

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #invalidlogins) 
 BEGIN    


---Creating  HTML table
              SET @TableHTML3 = '<html><head><style>'
               + 'td {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:11pt;} ' 
               +'</style></head><body>' + '<div style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:5px; margin-bottom:15px; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.3em; font-family:calibri;">'
               + @ReportTitle3 + '</div>' + '<div style="margin-left:50px; font-family:Calibri;"><table cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1 border=1>' + '<tr bgcolor=#4b6c9e>'
               + '<td align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>A_LOGIN</b></font></td></tr>'

              DECLARE @EmailBody3 NVARCHAR(max)

              SELECT @EmailBody3 = (
                           SELECT td =A_SID
                                  ,td =A_LOGIN
                           FROM #invalidlogins
                           FOR XML RAW('tr')
                                  ,ELEMENTS
                           )

              SET @EmailBody3 = REPLACE(@EmailBody3, '<td>', '<td align=center><font face="calibri">')
              SET @EmailBody3 = REPLACE(@EmailBody3, '</td>', '</font></td>')
              SET @EmailBody3 = REPLACE(@EmailBody3, '_x0020_', SPACE(1))
              SET @EmailBody3 = REPLACE(@EmailBody3, '_x003D_', '=')
              SET @EmailBody3 = REPLACE(@EmailBody3, '<TRRow>0</TRRow>', '')

              SET @TABLEHTML3 = @TABLEHTML3 + @EmailBody3 + '</table></div></body></html>'
              SET @TABLEHTML3 = '<div style="color:Black; font-size:11pt; font-family:Calibri; width:100px;">' + @TableHTML3 + '</div>'

              DROP TABLE #invalidlogins




         SET @Mergedtable = @TableHTML+@TableHTML2+@TableHTML3+@TableHTML5+@TableHTML7

       EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'SQLDBA Profile'
                     ,@recipients = @emailrecipients 
                     ,@Body = @Mergedtable
                     ,@subject = @EmailSubject
                     ,@Body_format = 'HTML'

     -- Send the mail in this block as well.
    END

END


GO
```

Comment: While modifying @emailbody it is giving an error 'Replace function requires 3 argument' why so ?

Comment: @Teja What did you modify on @emailbody? This answer was only related to modifying the first IF ELSE block. What was changed to get that error?

Comment: @Teja have  you added the sp_sendmail proc to the `IF EXISTS` block?  The query posted does not  include the actual sending of the mails.

Comment: Now i made the changes only in the IF ELSE condition still receiving an empty mail

Comment: @Teja The  ELSE should not even exist if you don't want to send a mail. Everything needs to be inside the IF. Can you add the whole script to the question? the sending of the mail is not in your script. How are you sending the mail?

Comment: Added the total script please take a look

Comment: @Teja Added the script, see EDIT 2